# getting class attribute of radio button in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the class attribute of checked radio button, with name="radio".
Used the code that's working fine in Firefox, but fails in IE.

```
val = $('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').attr('class');
```

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no psuedo-class `:radio`. I think you meant `[type=radio]`.

Comment: <input type=radio name=radio class="soneval"/>one <input type=radio name=radio class="anotherval"/>two -> i need to get the class value of selected radio button -> eg :- somevalue

Comment: Well excuse me for being old-fashioned, but I always use `querySelector`. Besides, from that page: "Because :radio is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :radio cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="radio"] instead."

Comment: @Kolink there is a psuedo selector `:radio` as @ stewe mentioned, @user976034 as lolink mentioned try `[type='radio']` IE sometimes doesn't like the psuedo selectors

Comment: 'null' is null or not an object im getting

Answer (score 0):

As comments says, I think you should use type instead of name. But i think you have named your input as radio because you can find this specific input. If you just use type selector you will catch every single selected radio input on page.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" class="ey"  /> Male<br />
```

So, if your page have more forms, you should specify a parent or form to avoid conflicts. Set a id for your form and try to find it by form id and radio type like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="ey" /> Male<br />
</form>  


val =  $("#myform input[type='radio']:checked").attr('class');
```

I hope it can help you :)